# How to delete PFFile's cache

Tags: ios, caching, parse-platform, pffile

I'm using Parse and PFFile and developing iOS app that provide audio contents.

And when I download new mp3 file from cloud, the data look to be saved locally as cache.
Caching itself is good.

But my problem is since each audio content is around 3mb and storage usage of my app keep increasing.
I want to delete old local cache manually.

It is possible? and how can I delete cached files?

[UPDATED]

Heres my code.
Basically I download mp3 data from parse cloud by using getDataInBackgroundWithBlock.

```
// lessonObj is PFObject
let lessonFile = lessonObj["mp3"] as PFFile
lessonFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (mp3Data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    if ( error == nil ) {
        // next step
    } else {
        // println("error")
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: [PFQuery clearAllCachedResults]; This clears all caches. I am not 100% sure if it will clear images too but give it a try.

Comment: I caution clearing the cache frequently though as you will either be performing too many network calls and hit your parse limit, or your app will end up using a ton of network data.

Comment: Did my method work for you?

Comment: To tell the truth, I'm not sure. It seems no as far as I checked the Settings App. "Settings"->"General"->"Usage"->"Manage Storage"->"My App" But only solution looks PFQuery.clearAllCachedResults(). And I have no idea whether Setting App is wrong or the method just set the deleted flag and actually delete files later.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In order to clear the cache you would need to use the following function.

```
[PFQuery clearAllCachedResults];
```

Comment: Thank you for responding me. But unfortunately it doesn't seem delete disk cache because storage usage doesn't change.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your code where you cache the objects?

Comment: Not sure why I just got a downvote if the asker chose mine as correct.

Answer (score 0):

[PFFile clearAllCachedDataInBackground];